# Creating 'duplicate' cells in other Excel (2010) Sheets including formatting

Tags: excel

Just hoping someone can help - I've been experimenting and googling for ages with no success!

On Excel 2010, I would like to copy a range of cells from one sheet (say, Sheet 1) to another in the same workbook.  I need the copy to have the contents of the cells AND their formatting AND to mirror any changes which happen to either the contents or formatting of those cells in Sheet 1.

Is there any way I can do this please?  Please note, I'm not familiar with using VBA so if that's needed I'll need some instructions about how to use/copy any code solutions you give me into my workbook too?

Comment: Reflecting changes to formatting is going to be especially tricky. What is the general purpose for this exact copy of a range? If it's simply for display, you might be able to use the [Camera tool](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/oddity/the_camera_tool/).

Comment: if you select both sheets (press CTRL while selecting sheet tabs) everything you do on sheet1 is replicated on sheet2

Answer (score 0):

if you select both sheets (press CTRL while selecting sheet tabs) everything you do on sheet1 is replicated on sheet2

so select both sheets

select a cell or range of cells

format and enter content as desired

untie sheets (press CTRL while selecting sheet tabs)

sheet2 is a duplicate of sheet 1

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

To duplicate cells on Sheet 1 on Sheet 2, even when entering new rows on sheet 1

Enter `ROW()` in every row of column "A" in sheet one. This duplicates the row number to be used for your `vlookup`.

On Sheet 2 for every cell you wish to duplicate:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(),'Sheet 1'!$A:$G,COLUMN()+1,FALSE),"")`

When entering a new row on Sheet 1, you will need to copy the `ROW()` function to the first column of the new row.

All other adjustments are automatic except adding columns. Adding columns requires additional steps.